# JS inheritance with/without using prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am trying to learn inheritance. If I am defining my method `superPrint()` in SuperClass, I am unable to execute using the child instance

eg: `new ChildClass().superPrint();` //Throws error fn not available

```
/*Parent Class*/
var SuperClass= function(){
  this.name = '';
  this.superPrint = function(){console.log('Doesnt Work');};
}

/*Child Class*/
var ChildClass= function(){
    this.print=function(){
        console.log('Always works');
    }
}

/*Child method inheriting from the parent method*/
ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);

/*Instantiating the child method*/ 
var obj = new ChildClass();
obj.print();//This works
obj.superPrint();//This gives error *******
```

But if the function `superPrint()` is defined using prototype it works. Why?
(called using `new ChildClass().workingPrint();` now it will work)

```
/*Parent Class*/
var SuperClass= function(){
   this.name = '';
}

SuperClass.prototype.workingPrint = function(){console.log('This Works');};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this.superPrint is a method on the instances SuperClass will create. Since you only copy the prototype over into ChildClass and not create a SuperClass instance for your ChildClass, it won't contain the instance methods.

If you want to use object.create, you could add something like `SuperClass.call(this);` to the definition of your ChildClass, in addition to copying the prototype.

Comment: Can you explain in detail or suggest some material

Comment: The MDN entry is quite nice in explaining, but can be a bit expansive: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain  For the classical way of doing inheritance with 'new', I liked crockfords explanation: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html For a very in depth explanation, the inheritance chapters in 'secrets of the javascript ninja' book by john resig are quite nice. I'm trying to find a good simple explanation for object.create + call, but can't immediately find the one I used to read.

Comment: OK and also my actual question was why I cant define an inner function. If I define a fn using prototype it works but the block 1 doesnt

Answer (score 0):

I think that if the function of your `SuperClass` is not explicitely defined to be prototyped it is not available to any object of your `ChildClass`. If that is not the case, your instance of `ChildClass` will not have access to the functions of a `SuperClass` instance

Therefore, this will work:

```
SuperClass= function(){
}
SuperClass.prototype.superPrint = function(){
    console.log('Use prototype to inherit');
};
ChildClass= function(){
    this.print=function(){
    }
}
ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);

var obj = new ChildClass();
obj.print();
obj.superPrint();
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fcw7c1x/) in case one wants to play around :)